# How do I move the star into the place it belongs

Tags: java, recursion

[image]
That is my homework assignment in the link above. This is what I did so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bowling {

public static void recursionPins(int n, int t) {

    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.print("\t\t");
        for (int i = 1; i <= t - 1; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println("*");
    } else {
        recursionPins(n - 1, t);
        for (int i = 1; i <= t - n; i++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            System.out.print("* ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}

// main method
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of rows of pins: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    recursionPins(n, n);
    }
}
```

When I run it, the first * is out of place and I'm not sure what the error is. The link below is a sample run of the program.

```
Enter number of rows of pins: 10
                 *
        * * 
       * * * 
      * * * * 
     * * * * * 
    * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

I'm not sure how to move the star over.

Comment: No one is going to click on random spam-like external link. Please read [mcve] and include everything relevant in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in the base case:

```
if (n == 1) {

    System.out.print("\t\t");
    for (int i = 1; i <= t - 1; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");

    System.out.println("*");
}
```

You are printing two tabs *and* the required number of spaces. You need to remove `System.out.print("\t\t");`:

```
if (n == 1) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= t - 1; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("*");
}
```

***Output:***

```
Enter number of rows of pins: 5
    *
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```